# Is there a way to get an Object from an Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop

Coding in javascript, and I am trying to put objects into arrays, and the Array looks like

```
arr = [
{"id":1,"location":"Place1"},
{"id":2,"location":"Place2"}
]
```

I am trying to do arr[1].location, but arr[1] is undefined and console.log(arr[0]) and arr[1] in inspect element just returns as a "{". Im not sure if this is a chrome thing, but node does seem to accept the format.

Edit: I am collecting from a api that I made and this is the format it returns the code, I am just trying to access variable location. I am asking how would I get said variable

Problem answered in comments, didn't parse data.

Comment: Where and how are you defining `arr` (it's not in your question)? When and where are you then trying to access `arr[0]`, `arr[1]`, etc? _"Inspect element"_ is for DOM (HTML) elements so I'm not sure what that has to do with your question at all

Comment: Your code should work fine, try assigning the variable `arr` like so:

`let arr = [
  { "id": 1, "location": "Place1" },
  { "id": 2, "location": "Place2" }
];
console.log(arr[1].location);`

Comment: Could you please address **all** the questions in the first comment above? Given now you mention an API, I suspect this will answer your question but will wait to see what you think ~ [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I made the array into a variable now so It is not confusing. I noticed theres no arr in code so I also fixed it. And yes metaphorical "arr" is defined but "arr[0]" is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try parsing your data when received :

```js
JSON.parse(apiResponse)
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem was the way I handled the data. Instead of using a XMLHttpRequest for the array, I used jquery to request the data, and that seemed to work better for my API.